# Can we reopen the question "Which format is most common for representing a number range in U.S. punctuation style and in British punctuation style?"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

I have edited the question [Which format is most common for representing a number range in U.S. punctuation style and in British punctuation style?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/362220/which-format-is-best-for-a-number-range) so that it now asks a factual question about whether a predominant punctuation style in the U.S. and in the UK exists for handling inclusive numerical ranges (such as dates or page numbers).

The original question asked "which style is better"—which is obviously a request for opinion-based answers and which led to its being closed for that reason. However, I think that specific questions about whether a predominant style exists—and, if so, what that style is—are answerable by checking to see whether a broad consensus among style guides on a particular style exists or does not exist. Further, I think that an answer presenting evidence on questions of this sort may be valuable for readers who care about such things.

With these points in mind, I ask that you consider reopening this question as edited. Thanks!

Comment: I certainly would like to see it opened. Not that we need a better answer, but it should be up front, not hidden. Do I hafta  make that an answer to have it count?

Comment: @JohnLawler: The question has been reopened—and as a result, Laurel has marked my question here with the 'status-completed' tag. Thanks!